# Want to logout from my account if i update the App in IOS (Objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, logout

I want to logout from **MYAPP** if user update these app from **appStore** or appBlade.
How to make these possible?

How do i know user is updating the app so i will **erase/clear** all data store in memory?

please help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: why you will logout on updating app? that is kinda bad idea...

Comment: i know. but Client requirement is like that. :)

Comment: kill that client..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do i know user is updating the app so i will erase/clear all data store in memory?

If the app is updated, any running copy will necessarily be killed, so anything you have in memory will go away. Data that's stored in files will be preserved, of course. If you want to detect that a new version of the app is running, have the app first try to read some value (like it's own version) from the user defaults or from some file determined by you. If you don't find the expected value, then write it there; now you know that this is the first time that this new version of the app has run. The next time this version of the app runs, it will find the value (because you wrote it the first time) and know that this is NOT the first time this version of the app has run.

Answer (score 3):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]];
```

This code you can use to find the app version. You can compare this with the previous version and log out the User from app.

Answer (score 3):

When a people updating,you can judge the APP version.
Like this:

```
let currentVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary![kCFBundleVersionKey as String]
```

If the APP version is new，you can erase/clear all data store in memory.